# How do you #include files in Java?

Tags: java, include

Coming from a C++ environment I got used to splitting up many of the functions that I needed into an `funcs.h` file and then do `#include "funcs.h"` and then adding the functions prototypes into the main .cpp file.

Now I am starting to work with Java (mainly with [Minecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) ModloeaderMp), and I already made a `funcs.java` file where there are some premade functions (e.g., some functions for file copying, giving stacks of items, etc.). Since I am already using the statement `Public class mod_mine extends BaseModMp`, is there a way I can import the functions or do I can I just do another `Public class mod_mine extends funcs`?

Comment: C++ knowledge doesn't directly transfer to Java even though they are similar. There really are many pitfalls and many things that are done differently. There are a large number of tutorials aimed specifically at people who are used to C++ however, try googling `java for c++ programmers`.

Comment: All the answers are lacking examples.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417291/no-simple-way-to-include-in-java) (from 2009). And [from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025239/include-include-equivalent-in-java).

Comment: Related: *[How does Java import work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620369/how-does-java-import-work)*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't `#include` in Java; you `import package.Class`. Since Java 6 (or was it 5?), you can also `import static package.Class.staticMethodOfClass`, which would achieve some forms of what you're trying to do.

Also, as @duffymo noted, `import` only saves you from systematically prefixing the imported class names with the package name, or the imported static method names with the package and class name. The actual `#include` semantics doesn't exist in Java - at all.

That said, having a "funcs.java" file seems to me like you are starting to dip your toes into some anti-patterns... And you should stay away from these.

Comment: Nitpick: it's `import static package.Class.staticMethodOfClass`, if you leave out the static it won't build.

Comment: import is not at all the same thing as a #include in C++.  All the import does is let you type Baz instead of foo.bar.Baz.  It's a keystroke saving device, nothing more.

Comment: @duffymo I don't imply it's the same as an include, I probably should have made it clear-er. My core point here was the static import, which appears to be what the OP looks for - somehow.

Comment: Yes, you should.  I read it to say that it's exactly equivalent.  Don't worry about what the OP is looking for; make sure the answers are correct.

Comment: @duffymo Have added a paragraph specifically about this.

Comment: @duffymo I certainly didn't read it as "exactly equivalent". It sounds like you're assuming quite a bit from very little text. More like that was his only alternative because there *isn't* an exact equivalent.

Comment: @Thor84no I believe duffymo downvoted because it was indirectly implying `import` was semantically equivalent to `#include`, which is wrong. Now that it's fixed he should remove the downvote.

Comment: Done.  Your answer changed quite a lot from the first reading.

Comment: @Romain Yeah his comment wasn't on here as I was typing that.

Answer (score 9):

There's no `#include` in Java.

I would not like a design that had a `funcs.java` that stored all the variables.  Objects are state and behavior encapsulated into a single component.  You aren't designing in an object-oriented way if you do that.

Good names matter.  A class named `Stuff` that extends `Stuff2` had better just be a poor example.

That's not good Java.  I wouldn't consider it to be good C++, either.

Comment: Ok, <code>funcs.java</code> just contains FUNCTIONS that I use frequently, not variables. Stuff and Stuff2 are just dummy examples. What I meant is that I am doing already a class extend, so I was wondering if I could do it again.

Comment: If code is common between *similar* Classes it makes sense to make a base Class and placing the methods there. That doesn't mean you should make a library of whatever useful generic methods you may have in a single Class and always extend that. You can extend a Class as many times as you like and you can extend an extended Class, but you can't extend more than a single Class (only interfaces, which you `implement` rather than `extend`).

Comment: Java only supports single inheritance of implementation, but you can implement as many interfaces as you'd like.  I don't know what "could do it again" means.  Sounds like you need to read a lot of basic Java.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're putting all your methods in the same class. You should separate them:

**Utility classes**

These should contain static methods that do things like get the contents of a file, show a dialog screen, or add two numbers together. They don't really belong in an object class, they don't require instances, and they're used widely throughout the program. See [java.lang.Math](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) for a good example of this.

**Constant class or configuration files**

This can be a `Constants` class that contains `static final` members, like `PI = 3.1415`. You can access them using `Constants.PI`.

Or, you can use configuration files and load them into `Configuration` and access the configuration variables with something like `config.get("database")`.

**Other**

If your code doesn't fit into any of these, you will want to put it into some class such that your code fits [object-oriented programming concepts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/). From your question, it sounds like you'll want to read up on this. I would first read *[Head First Java](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/)*, then maybe some other books on [object-oriented programming in Java](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java%20books#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=java%20object%20oriented%20programming%20book&pbx=1&oq=java%20object%20oriented%20programming%20book&aq=f&aqi=g1g-v2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1221l6370l0l6583l37l18l0l14l14l3l300l2981l1.13.3.1l26l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=18aa9f7b4fee5b6d&biw=1349&bih=780). After that, I'd look at some [design patterns](http://www.oodesign.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Java is an object-oriented programming language, and there is a reason for it.

There isn't any #include in Java, although you can import classes from other packages.
Making separate class, func.java, to store variables might not be a good idea, until or unless all of them are constants.

By extending some class, you can reuse the function. But does extending class pass the *is a* test? If not that, this might be a bad idea.

If moving from C++, going through some good book, for example, *[Head First Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_First_(book_series)#Books)* might help a lot.

Comment: C++ is object-oriented too; this is just bad design in every language.

Comment: @dyffymo agreed...just said so because C++ also supports programming without object oriented approach and java does'nt.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any #include in Java. You can use the *import* statement to make classes and interfaces available in your file.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the C preprocessor on a Java file, ensuring you use the -P flag to disable line annotations. A quick Google search confirms that this has been attempted at least twice, and is even used in the popular **fastutil** library:

- *[Using C style macros in Java](https://programming.guide/java/macros-in-java-source-files.html)*
- https://lyubomyr-shaydariv.github.io/posts/2016-09-06-fun-with-java-and-c-preprocessor/

This works for all directives (#include, #define, #ifdef, and so forth) and is both syntactically and semantically identical to the equivalent statements in C/C++.

Comment: The second link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

Actually... There is a way to have the same semantics as in C's #include (the keyword was later borrowed by C++ for the sake of looking fancy...). It's just not defined with the same words, but it does exactly what you are looking for.

First, let's see what you do with #include in C++ to understand the question:

- include `#defines`,
- "forward" function definitions (their "body" being defined elsewhere, in a class implementation, if you remember Turbo Pascal, you get my point),
- define structures,

and that's pretty much it.

For the structure definitions, there isn't any point. That's old-school C: in C++ you don't define `struct {}` anymore for ages; you define `class` structures with properties and accessor methods. It's the same in Java: no `typedef struct {}` here either.

For this, you have the "interface" declaration (see *[Interfaces (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)*):

It does exactly what you're looking for:

```
    public interface MyDefines {
        final CHAR_SPACE : ' ';               // ugly #define
        int detectSpace(FileInputStream fis); // function declaration
        // and so on
    }
```

Then, to use:

```
    public class MyClass extends MyAncestor implements MyDefines {
        ...
        // implementation of detectSpace()
        int detectSpace(FileInputStream fis) {
            int ret = 0;
            char Car;
            if((Car = fis.read()) != -1) && (Car == CHAR_SPACE)) ret++;
            ...
        }
```

Read the link given above; it's full of useful cases.