# How does Java import work?

Tags: java

I would like to know how the `import` statement works.

I'm asking this because I have the following `imports` in my project:

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.jna.highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.jna.highgui.cvGrabFrame;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.jna.highgui.cvReleaseCapture;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.colorfulwolf.webcamapplet.gui.ImagePanel;
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.jna.cxcore.IplImage;
```

I don't have these packages in my project, so, how will this be imported?

If I create a JAR file with all my classes, my server where will host this JAR file, has to be free Internet access to get these `package`?

I got some problem in my `Applet` that has these imports, and I'm asking this question, to understand if can be an Internet rule.

```
<applet code="com.colorfulwolf.webcamapplet.WebcamApplet"
archive="http://san.redenetimoveis.com/teste.jar, http://san.redenetimoveis.com/core.jar, http://san.redenetimoveis.com/javacv.jar, http://san.redenetimoveis.com/javase.jar, http://san.redenetimoveis.com/jna.jar, http://san.redenetimoveis.com/customizer.jar, http://san.redenetimoveis.com/jmf.jar, http://san.redenetimoveis.com/mediaplayer.jar, http://san.redenetimoveis.com/multiplayer.jar, http://san.redenetimoveis.com/sound.jar"
    height="550" width="550">
</applet>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is import done in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053658/how-is-import-done-in-java)

Comment: I read this thread but the thread don't answer my question

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In dynamic languages, when the interpreter `import`s, it simply reads a file and evaluates it.

In C, external libraries are located by the linker at compile time to build the final object if the library is *statically compiled*, while for *dynamic libraries* a smaller version of the linker is called at runtime which remaps addresses and so makes code in the library available to the executable.

In Java, `import` is simply used by the compiler to let you name your classes by their unqualified name, let's say `String` instead of `java.lang.String`. You don't really need to import `java.lang.*` because the compiler does it by default. However this mechanism is just to save you some typing. Types in Java are fully qualified class names, so a `String` is really a `java.lang.String` object when the code is run. Packages are intended to prevent name clashes and allow two classes to have the same *simple name*, instead of relying on the *old* C convention of prefixing types like this. `java_lang_String`. This is called *namespacing*.

BTW, in Java there's the *static import* construct, which allows to further save typing if you use lots of constants from a certain class. In a compilation unit (a .java file) which declares

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

you can use the constant `PI` in your code, instead of referencing it through `Math.PI`, and the method `cos()` instead of `Math.cos()`. So for example you can write

```
double r = cos(PI * theta);
```

Once you understand that classes are always referenced by their fully qualified name in the final bytecode, you must understand how the class code is actually loaded. This happens the first time an object of that class is created, or the first time a static member of the class is accessed. At this time, the `ClassLoader` tries to locate the class and instantiate it. If it can't find the class a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown (or a a `ClassNotFoundException` if the class is searched programmatically). To locate the class, the `ClassLoader` usually checks the paths listed in the `$CLASSPATH` environment variable.

To solve your problem, [it seems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet.html) you need an `applet` element like this

```
<applet
  codebase = "http://san.redenetimoveis.com"
  archive="test.jar, core.jar"
  code="com.colorfulwolf.webcamapplet.WebcamApplet"      
  width="550" height="550" >
```

BTW, you don't need to import the archives in the standard JRE.

Comment: And when a external package is called in my import, like google (look at my imports). What will be done ? I need a free internet access ?

Comment: It seems your archives must be put in the same location pointed to by `codebase`, and referenced by simple names `myjar.jar` and `foobar.jar`. See [this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet.html)

Comment: I tryied put the `<applet>` tag like you said, but doesn't work. You can saw my code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604767/load-dll-library-in-my-applet

Comment: Where is $CLASSPATH defined? Can I change it? Does each Java application have its own $CLASSPATH?

Comment: I think this is not really correct: ```If it can't find the class, a ClassNotFoundException is thrown.``` If the class loader doesn't find a class, it will throw `NoClassDefFoundError`

Answer (score 37):

Java's *import* statement is pure syntactic sugar. *import* is only evaluated at compile time to indicate to the compiler where to find the *names* in the code.

You may live without any *import* statements when you always specify the full qualified name of classes. Like this line doesn't need any *import* statement at all:

```
javax.swing.JButton but = new javax.swing.JButton();
```

The *import* statement will make your code more readable like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

JButton but = new JButton();
```

Comment: Good for using the term "[syntactical sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)"

Answer (score 3):

Import in Java does not work at all, as it is evaluated at compile time only.
(Treat it as shortcuts so you do not have to write fully qualified class names). At runtime there is no import at all, just FQCNs.

At runtime it is necessary that all classes you have referenced can be found by classloaders. (classloader infrastructure is sometimes dark magic and highly dependent on environment.) In case of an applet you will have to rig up your HTML tag properly and also provide necessary JAR archives on your server.

PS: Matching at runtime is done via qualified class names - class found under this name is not necessarily the same or compatible with class you have compiled against.

Comment: What happens, is that my applet stop in a line where I call a method that exist in a `import static com.googlecode.javacv.jna.highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture;`. But `localhost` works fine, I got this problem just when I hot the `jar` file in my server. So, if the `applet` stops in line where call a method that exists in this imported package, maybe a internet access rule can resolve ?

Comment: Post your object tag and directory structure.  Usually applets have access to server they come from

Answer (score 2):

`javac` (or `java` during runtime) looks for the `classes` being imported in the `classpath`. If they are not there in the `classpath` then `classnotfound` exceptions are thrown.

`classpath` is just like the `path` variable in a shell, which is used by the shell to find a command or executable.

Entire directories or individual jar files can be put in the `classpath`. Also, yes a `classpath` can perhaps include a path which is not local but is somewhere on the internet. Please read more about classpath to resolve your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

The classes which you are importing have to be on the classpath. So either the users of your Applet have to have the libraries in the right place or you simply provide those libraries by including them in your jar file. For example like this: [Easiest way to merge a release into one JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/java-easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file)

Comment: I host my `jar` file in my server, so I need to edit the classpath of my server to all users access the applet without problem ?

Comment: No, the applet will actually run on the client side. The client's classpath is the important one.

Comment: So I think the problem is not in my classpath, because in localhost the applet runs normally. But when I put the jar file in my server, the applet runs until found a method that are in a imported class like the import google. Don't generate error.

Comment: Try to specify the location of the missing .jar file in the archive tag of your applet (the html code you updated).