# Is Java's import keyword for source files or binary files?

Tags: java, import

I know I can include a class or collection of classes in my Java project using the `import` statement.

For example, `import java.io.utils.*` imports (i.e. makes available for use in my Java program) all the classes in the `java.io.utils` package.

My question is, do the classes in an imported package need to be compiled? Or can packages also include uncompiled Java files? If it can be either, when can we use class files and when can we use Java files?

Comment: You can't execute or reference uncompiled code.

Comment: What are you `include`ing when you include a header file in C++ then?

Comment: Importing in Java is nothing like including in C.

Comment: As for "you can't execute or reference uncompiled code", that makes sense. My thinking was that you could tell the compiler in an `import` statement where to get the source code that needs to be compiled in order to resolve a given dependency. Just a guess really, hence the question.

Comment: @shmosel: You certainly *can* refer to uncompiled code if the compiler knows where to find the source file. I'll add an example in my answer.

Comment: Read also ['import' in java vs. '#include' in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517618/import-in-java-vs-include-in-c-c)

Comment: @JonSkeet Of course. I meant that compiled code can't reference uncompiled code. Which I understand to be what OP is asking about.

Comment: Here's another good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053658/how-is-import-done-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Import just means "make the imported classes available by their simple names" - you can remove imports entirely if you use fully-qualified names everywhere. It's definitely not like `#include` in C for example.

When you compile, if you try to refer to uncompiled code it will be compiled at that point, assuming the compiler can guess where to find the source code. The result never refers to uncompiled code, because the compiler needs to know what each type exposes.

As a complete example, construct the following file structure:

```
// src/foo/A.java
package foo;
import bar.*;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B.sayHello();
    }
}

// src/bar/B.java
package bar;
public class B {
    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Then in the `src` directory, run:

```
javac foo/A.java
```

That will automatically compile `bar/B.java` - but wouldn't compile any other code that isn't referenced (potentially transitively).

I would strongly recommend against using this "compile on demand" behaviour anyway though - if you compile class A that depends on class B, it will compile B the *first* time, but after that if you change B and recompile A, the compiler won't recompile B. I would organize your code into appropriate projects, and always recompile a complete project at a time, adding a project's *output* directory to the classpath for a project that depends on it, rather than allowing compiling one project to recompile bits of another on demand.

(Note that this isn't talking about the incremental compilation that many IDEs support... that's a rather different matter, and is fine assuming it's been implemented properly.)

Comment: So `import` statements are simply labour-saving devices. Any class or package I reference in an `import` statement is already available for use because I've included the class/package on the classpath. If I wanted to avoid using `import` statements entirely I could just use fully qualified names.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike C, `import` in Java does not "copy" stuff. Packages in Java is simply a way of avoiding ambiguity. `javax.swing.Timer` and `java.utils.Timer` are different `Timer`s. When you say `import javax.swing.Timer`, you are telling the compiler that you mean `javax.swing.Timer`, not any other `Timer`.

All these things that you can import comes from the JDK or some other libraries you're using, or they are created by you. The classes that fall into the former category is already compiled (.class). The classes you created are compiled as well, when you do `javac`. You can't refer to any uncompiled classes. Since they are uncompiled, the computer does not know they exist.

The reason why your IDE knows your packages and classes before you compile your code is because IDEs are smart. They compile your code before you even notice it.

Comment: That's the core of it: you don't `import` code, you just `import` names.

Answer (score 0):

As Java documentation reports.

`You might have to set your CLASSPATH so that the compiler and the JVM can find the .class files for your types.`

link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/summary-package.html