# Import custom package into project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

```
IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 Community Edition
Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)
```

Hello,

I have created a package name called `com.insystems.gumball`

I have a class called Gumball with some functions.

```
package com.insystems.gumball;

public class Gumball {
    /* functions here */
}
```

Now I have created a new command line app project called gumball_test

```
package com.insystems.gumballtest;

import com.insystems.gumball;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gumball gb = new Gumball(5);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get a:

```
unused port statement
```

and

```
cannot resolve symbol gumball
```

Both these projects are in different directories as I want to keep all my packages in a directory that I can import whenever I need them.

I am new to Java and IntelliJ so I am not sure how can I set the path of my packages that can be used in my other projects?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your `import com.insystems.gumball;` line (this means import `gumball` class in `com.insystems` package). Since there is none, you get this error.

You need to import certain class

```
import com.insystems.gumball.Gumball;
```

or the whole package

```
import com.insystems.gumball.*;
```

[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620369/how-java-import-works) to clarify things more

Comment: Just quick question. I am coming from C/C++ so we always link the *.so and provide a path. In Java how does the import statement know where to find the package, if I haven't provided in path to where the package is located?

Comment: they're looked in the same package and in classpath. Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)

Comment: I understand what you mean by the importing the actual class. I have done that and just as expected I still get the cannot find symbol. I think this is because it doesn't know where to find it. I would like to keep my packages self-contained.

Comment: The question you're asking is all about classPath. Please read the wikipedia article and mainly this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html