# import statement in Java: classes imported are linked or copied?

Tags: java, class, import, scjp

`import` statement in Java: the classes imported are linked or copied? Copied to same directory? How these classes are treated/joined when compiled?

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620369/how-java-import-works)'s accepted answer at least partially answers your question, when it talks about class representations in compiled byte code and how the class loader works.

Answer (score 1):

They are neither linked nor copied.

It is possible to write Java code with no import statements at all.  You would need to fully qualify everything outside `java.lang` and not in the default package:

```
java.util.ArrayList<Integer> intList = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Importing classes is a convenience that allows the programmer not to have to fully qualify most class references.  It allows such classes to be referred to by their simple names.  With an `import` statement, there is no copying going on, and no linking.  The compiler will already search the classpath for the proper class, whether imported or fully qualified.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler do not include binaries from other classes into your class. If you use full name of class like `com.foo.bar.YourClass` in your code

```
com.foo.bar.YourClass instance = new com.foo.bar.YourClass();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then at runtime JVM will try to find `com/foo/bar/YourClass.class` binaries in one of directiries/jars specified in classpath, then will load it and use it.

Now in Java you can use short form of class name

```
YourClass
```

but to make it possible you need to specify where binaries for this class should be located (from which package it comes from) so they could be loaded at runtime. This problem solves `import` statement where

```
import com.foo.bar.YourClass;
```

means that wherever we will use `YourClass` we are using class from `com.foo.bar` package.

---

One of exception from this rule is when you use compilation-constants like

```
class Base{
    public static final SIZE = 100;
}

class Demo{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(Base.SIZE);
    }
}
```

which after compiling `Demo` class and later changing value of `SIZE` in `Base` class will still print `100` unless you will recompile `Demo` class again.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, neither. The import statement sort of provides an alias (it really pulls a name into the current namespace, but the programmer must resolve ambiguities) for commonly used classes. The fully qualified path provides location information for the runtime environment to load the classes.

Now, some IDEs will copy some libraries to a dist or build directory for simplified execution environments (or preparation for installer construction). This shouldn't be confused with linking or copying.