# import static method in xtned (generated java)

Tags: java, import, static, member

It is possible to import just one static method, or member in extend? I know that it is possible to import all static methods by *, like in this example ...

```
import static example.Types.*
```

But I need only one.

Comment: Answer edited, just in case you already readed it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is something like the `using` keyword from C# or C++ java doesn't have that feature.

> Java 5 added an import static option that allows static variables (typically constants) to be referenced without qualifying them with a class name.

For example, after

```
import static java.awt.Color;
```

It would then be possible to write

```
Color background = RED;
```

instead of

```
Color background = Color.RED;
```

*Example above have been taken from:*  [Java: packages and Import.](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html)
*The site used for the example seems to be out of date, sorry any trouble this can cause*

See [How java import works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620369/how-java-import-works) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

`import static System.out;`

You can then merely write

`out.println("Doobedoo");`

Which will save you from typing the `System.out` part several times over but is potntially confusing for anyone trying to follow you code.

Use it sparingly and generally only for constants ( static final ).