# How Does the import statement in java work?

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked many times but I still don't understand how the import statement works. I have a example of my problem as follows.

I have my main file for a simple game in the path: C:\myjavafiles\game.java, I have a file for creating Dwarves in a path called: C:\myjavafiles\dwarf.java, I also have a file for declaring job types in: C:\myjavafiles\support\jobTypes.java. My question is, how could I import dwarf.java and jobTypes.java into game.java if I have the code in each file as follows:

game.java:

```
// import dwarf.java and jobTypes.java here
class game {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  // Do something
 }
}
```

dwarf.java:

```
public class dwarf {
 public dwarf() {
  // setup dwarf
 }
}
```

jobTypes.java:

```
public class jobTypes {
 public jobTypes() {
  // Do something
 }
}
```

Thank you for you time.

EDIT:

I've add dwarf.java to the package support. And I've add this statement to game.java:

`import support.*;`

But that doesn't work.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: Have a look into package declaration. Also note that class names should begin with a capital letter by convention.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz that didn't help any, I don't want to know about packages.

Comment: Well if you don't want to know about them, forget about importing

Comment: @Programmer2120 - So why do you think that yet another explanation is going to help you understand where the many previous explanations have not helped?

Comment: @StephenC Because as of yet I haven't seen anyone show a example, they just go into long winded speeches about the import statement. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620369/how-java-import-works)

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz Why?

Comment: The import statement ebabies you to use classes stored in other packages. So you must understand what a package is before you can understand the import statement

Comment: If you don't understand packages, you won't understand how to import classes. What might be confusing you is that your directory structure (where you're storing your *.java files) must reflect the package structure. If every class is in the same package, you do not need to use import statements for those classes, but you still will need them for other classes, e.g., `java.io.InputStream`.

Comment: Where is a good place to read up of packages?

Answer (score 0):

> import Statements
>   An import statement is a way of making more of the functionality of Java available to your program. Java can do a lot of things, and not every program needs to do everything. So, to cut things down to size, so to speak, Java has its classes divided into "packages." Your own classes are part of packages, too.

No import Needed

The simple Hello.java program doesn't have any import statements:

```
public class Hello{
  public static void main(String arg[]){
  System.out.println("Hello.");
}
```

}

> Everything in the program is already available to the compiler. The compiler can access any class in the java.lang package without needing an import statement. It can also access any classes in the "local" package, which is any classes defined in files in the same directory as the program being compiled that aren't part of another package (that is, they don't have a package statement at the start of the file.)

import Required

> Anything that isn't in the java.lang package or the local package needs to be imported. An example is the Scanner class. If you look up the Scanner class in the Java API Specification, you'll see that it is in the java.util package.

Comment: I'd need to know about how to import, not when. Thanks for the answer just the same.

Comment: Are using an IDE eclipse or Netbeans?

Comment: Nether, I'm use a commandline and notepad++